# Java JSONArray JSONObject["NI"] not found

Tags: java, arrays, json, xml, org.json

Hey all I am running into an interesting problem. Seems that the Json **(org.json.JSONArray)** can not find the element **"NI"** even though its >>>right there<<<

My XML:

```
  <soap:Header>  </soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <Multi_search_NI_response xmlns:sear="http://www.identitysystems.com/xmlschema/iss-version-11/searchSvc" response="0">
        <NIResult>
            <NI>
                <score>100</score>
                <ID>64973020020</ID>
                <FULL_NAME>Bob Showcase Barker</FULL_NAME>
                <FIRST_NAME>Bob</FIRST_NAME>
                <LAST_NAME>Barker</LAST_NAME>
                <DOB>11/23/1982</DOB>               
                <CL_ID/>
            </NI>
            <NI>
                <score>87</score>
                <ID>54619738215</ID>
                <FULL_NAME>Steve apple jobs</FULL_NAME>
                <FIRST_NAME>Steve</FIRST_NAME>
                <LAST_NAME>Jobs</LAST_NAME>
                <DOB>10/22/1992</DOB>
                <CL_ID/>
            </NI>
        </NIResult>
    </Multi_search_NI_response>
</soap:Body>
```

Into JSON:

```
{
    "soap:Header": "",
    "soap:Body": {
        "Multi_search_NI_response": {
            "xmlns:sear": "http://www.identitysystems.com/xmlschema/iss-version-11/searchSvc",
            "response": 0,
            "NIResult": {
                "NI": [{    
                        "CL_ID": "",
                        "LAST_NAME": "Barker",
                        "FIRST_NAME": "Bob",
                        "score": 100,
                        "NRI_ID": 64973020020,
                        "DOB": "11/23/1982",
                        "FULL_NAME": "Bob Showcase Barker"
                    }, {
                        "CL_ID": "",
                        "LAST_NAME": "Jobs",
                        "FIRST_NAME": "Steve",
                        "score": 87,
                        "NRI_ID": 54619738215,
                        "DOB": "11/23/1982",
                        "FULL_NAME": "Steve apple Jobs"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Jsondata = {"soap:Header":"","soap:Body":{"Multi_search_NI_response":{"xm...
>
> path = C:\Repository\xml2JsonPretty/DownloadedXML/2
>
> _tmpRecieved = `<soap:Header></soap:Header><soap:Body><Multi_search_NI_response xmlns:sear="http://www.identitysystems.com/xmlschema/iss-version-11/searchSvc" response="0"><NIResult><NI><score>100</score><ID>64973020020</ID>...`

As you see "NI" is right there yet it says *nope!*

```
final class MyResult {
    final File file;
    final String csv;
    final CsvToExcel excel;

    public MyResult(File file, String csv, CsvToExcel excel) {
        this.file = file;
        this.csv = csv;
        this.excel = excel;
    }

    public File getFile() { return file; }
    public String getCSV() { return csv; }      
    public CsvToExcel getExcel() { return excel; }
}

private static MyResult CSVFromJSON(JSONObject jsondata, String path) {
    try {
        //Now create CSV from JSON:
        JSONArray docs   = jsondata.getJSONArray("NI");
        File file        = new File(CSVName);
        String csv       = CDL.toString(docs);                  
        xml2json x2j     = new xml2json();
        CsvToExcel excel = x2j.new CsvToExcel();
        MyResult myR     = x2j.new MyResult(file, csv, excel);

        return myR;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}
```

And how I am calling it (the **_tmpRecieved** houses the XML string):

```
try {
        JSONObject jsondata     = CSVToJSON(_tmpRecieved);
        MyResult csvdata        = CSVFromJSON(jsondata, path);
        String ExcelFilePath    = CSVToExcel(csvdata, path);

        System.out.println("ExcelPath: " + ExcelFilePath);              
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

And this is the spot where that error shows up:

```
JSONArray docs   = jsondata.getJSONArray("NI");
```

The offical error:

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["NI"] not found.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: try to find `NIResult` instead of `NI`. JSONArray docs   = jsondata.getJSONArray("NIResult");

Comment: @AbinashGhosh I need to start *after* NI....

Comment: After converting json there is no `NI`, `NIResult` contains array of object `NI`

Comment: `NiResult` is an array, `Ni` is an object, and neither of them are top-level. You need to get those top level objects and then get the child objects from them. Right now you have the top level Object (`jsondata`) which is `Multi_search_NI_response`, which has only `NiResult` as a child

Comment: *"My JSON in question"* That's XML, not JSON. Why are you using a JSON parser to parse SOAP XML?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've added some more information to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

@Rogue answered your question.

What you are doing is search the JSONArray "NI" inside the JSONObject "jsondata".

"NI" isn't inside the JSONObject "jsondata", **but is** in the JSONObject "NIResult". You have to travel to the JSONObject "NIResult" to succesfully get the JSONArray.

You can travel using:

```
JSONObject soapBody = jsondata.getJSONObject("soap:Body");
JSONObject response = soapBody.getJSONObject("Multi_search_NI_response");
JSONObject result = response.getJSONObject("NIResult");
JSONArray docs = result.getJSONArray("NI");
```

Note: is better to parameterize action like this